# Documentation for pip the python package (rather than the command line tool)

Tags: python, documentation, pip

When you install pip, you get a Python package as well as a command line tool. For example, you can print a list of Python packages like this:

```
import pip

print pip.get_installed_distributions()
```

However I can't find any documentation for this package. Searching some of the function names doesn't come up with anything, and sites like PyPi and Wikipedia link to the [command line docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/).

Is using pip via `import pip` documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the pip API is neither documented nor guaranteed to be stable. There are [proposals](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues?q=label%3A%22C%3A+public+api%22+) to rectify this, but not much progress.

If you're looking to play around with the internals, there are some examples of usage [here](http://www.programcreek.com/python/index/564/pip), but beware that the API could change in later versions.

**Update, October 2022:**

The [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program) now states:

> While it is implemented in Python, and so is available from your Python code via import pip, you must not use pip’s internal APIs in this way.